# Biblatex alphanumeric

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to remove the + sign in the cite of a reference, when using the alphanumeric? Why is the + diplayed?

```
@ARTICLE{Yang:2004:SecurityAdhoc,
author={Hao Yang and Haiyun Luo and Fan Ye and Songwu Lu and Lixia Zhang},
journal={Wireless Communications, IEEE},
title={Security in mobile ad hoc networks: challenges and solutions},
year={2004},
volume={11},
number={1},
pages={38-47},
}
```

[YLY+04] H. Yang, H. Luo, F. Ye, S. Lu y L. Zhang, “Security in mobile ad hoc net-
works: challenges and solutions”, Wireless Communications, IEEE, vol. 11, n. o
1, págs. 38-47, 2004.

Comment: The `+` is displayed to show that some names were omitted when creating the label, it is the `alphabetic` equivalent of "et al.", try `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}`, or play around with the `maxalphanames`/`minalphanames` options.